# R: Repeat operation n times and store in vector

Tags: r, loops, vector, export-to-csv, repeat

I have the following code to randomly-sample 3 out of 8 observations and then calculate the coefficient of variation (CV).

```
d <- c(4.34238,4.32101,4.35023,4.44773,4.24697,4.08944,4.28733,4.46353)

# Random sampling with replacement:
i <- sample(1:8, 3, replace=TRUE)
X <- d[i]

meanX <- mean(X)
sdX <- sd(X)
cvX <- (sdX/meanX)*100
cvX
```

The thing is, i would like to bootstrap this for say, 10000 times and store the values in a vector or export as a csv so that i can later calculate an average CV.

I found codes (i) for repeating operations n times; and (ii) for exporting values separately. How do i do this together?
Thank you.

Extra question...
Which is a more efficient way:- 
(i) Randomly sample 3/8 observation every time, calculate CV, store the values?
(ii) Generate 10000 sets of sampled observations, calculate CV, store the values?

Comment: Can you please give a reproducible example for `d`? That is, don't post links (or pictures for that matter) for data, but rather post something we can easily copy/paste in our session

Comment: Edited the question to your request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've made a matrix of random numbers in vector `d` to be able to run something, but maybe you can use the code below to make it work! Greets!

```
d <- matrix(rnorm(100000), ncol=2)

n_bootstraps <- 50
cvX_vec = rep(0, n_bootstraps)

for (i in 1:n_bootstraps){
  i <- sample(1:8, 3, replace=TRUE)
  X <- d[i,2]
  meanX <- mean(X)
  sdX <- sd(X)
  cvX_vec[i] <- (sdX/meanX)*100
}

write.csv(x = cvX_vec, file = "./blah.csv")
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `replicate` to create a matrix with all the iterations:

```
myfun <- function(){
  i <- sample(1:8, 3, replace=TRUE)
  X <- d[i,2]

  c(meanX = mean(X), sdX = sd(X), cvX = sd(X)/mean(X) * 100)
}

result <- replicate(5, myfun)
```

This can be exported to a csv file using `write.table`:
    write.table(result, "result.csv")